# Optimizing for loop in Matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop

I'm writing a "Peak finder" in Matlab. I've never used Matlab or anything similar before this project, so I'm new to "vectorizing" my code. Essentially, the program needs to take a video of molecules and plot circles on the molecules present in each frame of the video. If a molecule is crowded then it gets a red circle, but if it is not crowded it gets a green circle.

My problem is that some of these videos have 2000 frames and my program takes up to ~25 seconds to process a single frame, which is not practical.

Using tic and toc I've found the trouble maker: A for-loop which calls a function that contains a for-loop.

```
function getPeaks( orgnl_img, processed_img, cut_off, radius )

    % find large peaks peaks by thresholding, i.e. you accept a peak only 
    % if its more than 'threshold' higher than its neighbors
    threshold = 2*std2(orgnl_img);
    peaks = (orgnl_img - processed_img) > threshold;

    % m and n are dimensions of the frame, named peaks
    [m, n] = size(peaks);

    cc_centroids = regionprops(peaks, 'centroid');

    % Pre-allocate arrays
    x_centroid = zeros(1, length(cc_centroids));
    y_centroid = zeros(1, length(cc_centroids));

    for i = 1:length(cc_centroids)
        % Extract the x and y components from cc_centroids struct
        x_centroid(i) = cc_centroids(i).Centroid(1);
        y_centroid(i) = cc_centroids(i).Centroid(2);

        row = int64(x_centroid(i));
        col = int64(y_centroid(i));

        % Assure that script doesnt attempt to exceed frame
        if col-2 > 0 && row-2 > 0 && col+2 < m && row+2 < n
            region_of_interest = orgnl_img(col-2:col+2,row-2:row+2);
            local_intensity = max(region_of_interest(:));

            % Do not plot circle when intensity is 'cut off' or lower
            if local_intensity > cut_off

               dist_bool = findDistance(cc_centroids, x_centroid(i), y_centroid(i), radius);

               if dist_bool == 1
                   color = 'g';
               else
                   color = 'r';
               end
               plotCircle(color, x_centroid(i), y_centroid(i), radius)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

And here is the findDistance function which contains another for-loop and determines if the circles overlap:

```
function dist_bool = findDistance( all_centroids, x_crrnt, y_crrnt, radius )
    x_nearby = zeros(1, length(all_centroids));
    y_nearby = zeros(1, length(all_centroids));
    for i = 1:length(all_centroids)
        if all_centroids(i).Centroid(1) < (x_crrnt+2*radius) &&...
           all_centroids(i).Centroid(1) > (x_crrnt-2*radius) &&...
           all_centroids(i).Centroid(2) < (y_crrnt+2*radius) &&...
           all_centroids(i).Centroid(2) > (y_crrnt-2*radius)

            x_nearby(i) = all_centroids(i).Centroid(1);
            y_nearby(i) = all_centroids(i).Centroid(2);
            pts_of_interest = [x_nearby(i),y_nearby(i);x_crrnt,y_crrnt];
            dist = pdist(pts_of_interest);
            if dist == 0 || dist > 2*radius
                dist_bool = 1;
            else
                dist_bool = 0;
                break
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I think that there must be much improvement to be done here. I would appreciate any advice.

Thanks! :)

**UPDATE:** Here are the profiler results. The first section of code is the "getPeaks" function

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaLdH.png

The hold comes from the plot circle function:

```
function plotCircle( color, x_centroid, y_centroid, radius )
    hold on;
    th = 0:pi/50:2*pi;
    xunit = radius * cos(th) + x_centroid;
    yunit = radius * sin(th) + y_centroid;
    plot(xunit, yunit, color);
    hold off;
end
```

Comment: you can use MATLAB profiler to get the exact function calls that are taking the most amount of time and then try to optimize those specific lines

Comment: Could you add some sample data as well... And please don't add a screenshot. Make it easy so that we can just copy and paste it into Matlab,

Comment: I have added the profiler results. I'm unsure how I can give you sample data. I have the .mat files for orgnl_img and processed_img, but I don't know how to give them to you. Sorry, I was hoping my problems would be more blatant.